# DNS options windows 7 aren't saved?

Tags: windows-7, networking, dns

I'm trying to use a free DNS (such as Google's: `8.8.8.8` / `8.8.4.4`) by typing this in thoses options:

[image]

But when I click on "validate settings upon exit" and "ok", the network diagnostic tool from Windows is launched and says that it didn't find any problems.

Then I have a window that forces me to reboot my PC for validating the new properties.

The problem is when the reboot is done, the DNS properties that I entered before aren't saved so it doesn't work. How should I do this?

I already tried to flush DNS cache whithout success.

Is that normal that I have to reboot each time I configure some DNS properties?

Comment: What sort of network adapter is this? Have you tried entering the settings without using the *validate* option?

Comment: It's Broadcom 802.11n and yes i tried it too but it doesn't seem to save the changes ... Maybe it's an OS issue and not DNS problem ?

Comment: Do you have any software from your ISP installed that might be acting like a watchdog and automatically "fixing" these settings?

Comment: Nop 0 software... And well since when windows should reboot for network settings ?

Comment: Agreed, something beyond Windows is at work here. I'd try booting into Safe Mode with Networking, change the settings, then immediately boot back into Safe Mode and see if they're still present. If they are, that tells you something running in Normal Mode is changing them on you.

Comment: That's a good idea i'll try it ! But for the moment I solved this using a proxy socks ;)